# Jupyter Notebook using wrong shell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Using Anaconda, when opening Jupyter notebook it tries to use the /etc/fish shell which I have uninstalled. Reinstalled Anaconda, and still tries to use fish shell.

```
[Command not found: /bin/fish]

[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

I have edited /etc/shells to not contain reference to fish as well.

Is there a way to edit the Jupyter Preferences, Or am I missing something else?

For reference: IPython qtconsole opens fine.

Comment: Is this for the terminal inside the notebook interface? If so, I think it looks at your `$SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: No for opening the notebook from the Continuum Navigator Page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that page; I don't know why it would invoke a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by:

Uninstalling iTerm2, Anaconda, fish and zsh shells.
Cleaning out /etc/shells file with references to fish and zsh

Edit Terminal (not iTerm2) bash_profile and /.bashrc file adding to top of files:

/.bashrc file:

```
export BASH_CONF="bash_profile"
```

/.bash_profile file:

```
export BASH_CONF="bashrc"
```

Reinstall Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and this is what I did, without reinstalling `Anaconda`. After removing fish using `apt remove fish` and deleting the line consisting `/usr/bin/fish` in `/etc/shells`, you need to do these additonal things:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/fish/     # getting rid of config leftovers
```

Also make sure there's no assignment in your bash profile about `fish`:

```
grep -i "fish" ~/.bashrc  # or ~/.profile if you use MacOS
```

Then as [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k) pointed out:

```
echo $SHELL    # mine showed /usr/bin/fish
export SHELL="/usr/bin/bash"
```

And finally type:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <user>
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

Done.